# iscsi login issue - 32 target not likely connected

Tags: iscsi

I'm experimenting with iSCSI. I set up a target on a VM and set up a second VM to UEFI network boot. In the `initramfs`, it tries to log in to the target and use a root filesystem from the iSCSI device. This all works. The problem is when I try to switch the initiator from a VM to a physical device. It netboots just fine and I can see diagnostics I logged in the `initramfs`. Where the VM normally emitted a message like `Connection1:0 to [target:......` to show that it logged in OK, the physical host instead logs a message: `initiator reported error (32 - target likely not connected)`. On the server, I see a non-descript message.

I believe I've reduced as many variables as I can. Both the VM initiator and the physical initiator are booting the same UEFI unified Linux kernel from TFTP, they're using the same initiator/target information, and the VM even has the same MAC as the physical host. (They are of course never both running at the same time). The only remaining variable I see is the network position. The VM's NIC is bridged to the same interface that the iSCSI target's NIC is bridged to. The physical host's NIC is on a different switch.

Is there any way to increase the logging verbosity on the iSCSI target to see if maybe it would log a better error? Alternatively, does the debug logging from the physical initiator mean anything to anyone? The time delta between `Setting login timer` and `poll not conntected 0`/`initiator reported error` is pretty much instant.

From a `tcpdump`, it's actually the initiator sending the FIN packet to the server, right after finishing the 3-way handshake. So what did `iscsistart` not like about the connection?

This error is only emitted in two places in the code, and only [this call site](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi/blob/bf035ee1784f28e81917c5bd9d930bf238f372e2/usr/iscsid_req.c#L159) would make sense in context. That is called only in two main paths, of which one [leads back to `iscsistart.c: login_session`](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi/blob/b680f6e81f2f05f7e721f0aa97ce8aa885b3f0ba/usr/iscsistart.c#L223-L265) which has a comment about a race condition :(

Initcpio hook:

```
modprobe iscsi_tcp
# ... dhcp ...
( 
  set -x
  ip route show
  ip route get 10.0.0.86
  ping -c1 10.0.0.86
  local INITIATOR=...
  local TARGET=...
  iscsistart -d6 -i "$INITIATOR" -t "$TARGET" -g 1 -a 10.0.0.86
) 2>&1 | while IFS='' read -r line; do
  # feed output slowly so I have a chance to read it
  echo "$line"
  sleep 1
done
set +x
# ... remainder of early userspace hooks ...
```

Physical host:

```
...
--- 10.0.0.86 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trp min/avg/max = 146.998/146.998/146.998 ms
Logging into iqn.....
Matched transport tcp
sysfs_attr_get_value: open `/class/iscsi_transport/tcp`/`handle`
sysfs_attr_get_value: open `/class/iscsi_transport/tcp`/`caps`
Allocated session 0x....
resolved 10.0.0.86 to 10.0.0.86
setting iface default, dev , set up , hw , transport tcp
set TCP recv window size to 524280, actually got 425984
set TCP send window size to 524280, actually got 425984
connecting to 10.0.0.86:3260
Setting login timer 0x... timeout 30
poll not connected 0
initiator reported error (32 - target likely not connected)
mgmt_ipc_write_rsp: rsp to fd 8
deleting a schelded/waiting thread!
Releasing session 0x...
iscsi child done
```

VM:

```
...
--- 10.0.0.86 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trp min/avg/max = 0.902/0.902/0.902 ms
Logging into iqn.....
Matched transport tcp
sysfs_attr_get_value: open `/class/iscsi_transport/tcp`/`handle`
sysfs_attr_get_value: open `/class/iscsi_transport/tcp`/`caps`
Allocated session 0x....
resolved 10.0.0.86 to 10.0.0.86
setting iface default, dev , set up , hw , transport tcp
set TCP recv window size to 524280, actually got 425984
set TCP send window size to 524280, actually got 425984
connecting to 10.0.0.86:3260
Setting login timer 0x... timeout 30
connected local port 39830 to 10.0.0.86:3260
expecting event 11, got 106, handling
....
Connection1:0 to [target:......
....
# system boots
```

Server (only when physical host tries to connect):

```
rx_data returned 0, expecting 48.
iSCSI Login negotiation failed.
```

tcpdump from Server:

```
21:48:19.467611 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43318, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.0.0.74 > 10.0.0.86: ICMP echo request, id 54272, seq 0, length 64
21:48:19.467661 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26507, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.0.0.86 > 10.0.0.74: ICMP echo reply, id 54272, seq 0, length 64
21:48:20.695909 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21194, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.0.0.74.46440 > 10.0.0.86.3260: Flags [S], cksum 0x13b8 (correct), seq 1762553309, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3433609716 ecr 0,nop,wscale 2], length 0
21:48:20.695974 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.0.0.86.3260 > 10.0.0.74.46440: Flags [S.], cksum 0x14ce (incorrect -> 0x9f88), seq 4180390614, ack 1762553310, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2735285892 ecr 3433609716,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:48:20.698368 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21195, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.0.74.46440 > 10.0.0.86.3260: Flags [.], cksum 0x8c0e (correct), ack 1, win 16384, options [nop,nop,TS val 3433609923 ecr 2735285892], length 0
21:48:21.515176 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21196, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.0.74.46440 > 10.0.0.86.3260: Flags [F.], cksum 0x88f4 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 16384, options [nop,nop,TS val 3433610716 ecr 2735285892], length 0
21:48:21.519590 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17461, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.0.86.3260 > 10.0.0.74.46440: Flags [.], cksum 0x14c6 (incorrect -> 0xc3bf), ack 2, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2735286715 ecr 3433610716], length 0
21:48:21.524522 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17462, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.0.86.3260 > 10.0.0.74.46440: Flags [F.], cksum 0x14c6 (incorrect -> 0xc3b9), seq 1, ack 2, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2735286720 ecr 3433610716], length 0
21:48:21.527019 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.0.74.46440 > 10.0.0.86.3260: Flags [.], cksum 0x8593 (correct), ack 2, win 16384, options [nop,nop,TS val 3433610752 ecr 2735286720], length 0
```

---

**Update:** After recompiling `open-iscsi` with additional logging and digging around the code a bit, I concluded something must be wrong with the way it is detecting the 1 second login timeout. It's a bit hard to follow the intended flow with all the actors / timeouts / alarms, but I managed to rip out enough of the code pertaining to login timeouts that it proceeded to the rest of the login process.

The minimal change to get it to work is to remove the login timeout in `login_session` in `iscsistart.c`, but I suspect that's actually just working around the real issue, which appears to be related to the TCP connect returning `EINPROGRESS` (despite the code explicitly setting the socket to non-blocking). Some retry actor should be running before some timeout actor (or the parent process) kills it, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

I couldn't help but notice that [this commit](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi/commit/9258c8eae046d98511d92912983778ca57ba201f) is the most recent commit to the file and happens to change a return code. I can't prove it's related (yet), but it seems suspect.

```
 static int login_session(struct node_rec *rec)
 {
        iscsiadm_req_t req;
        iscsiadm_rsp_t rsp;
        int rc, msec, err;
        struct timespec ts;
 
        rc = apply_params(rec);
        if (rc)
                return rc;
 
        printf("%s: Logging into %s %s:%d,%d\n", program_name, rec->name,
                rec->conn[0].address, rec->conn[0].port,
                rec->tpgt);
        memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
        req.command = MGMT_IPC_SESSION_LOGIN;
        memcpy(&req.u.session.rec, rec, sizeof(*rec));
 
        /*
         * Need to handle race where iscsid proc is starting up while we are
         * trying to connect. Retry with exponential backoff, start from 50 ms.
         */
        for (msec = 50; msec <= 15000; msec <<= 1) {
-               rc = iscsid_exec_req(&req, &rsp, 0, ISCSID_REQ_TIMEOUT);
+               rc = iscsid_exec_req(&req, &rsp, 0, -1);
```